# Working with phytoplankton data - functional diversity

Tags: r, biostatistics

I need help to understand how can I perform an analysis that was suggested by someone else with phytoplankton data. I need to calculate CWM of the community and then, calculate the significance of data variation among predictive variables.

First, to calculate CWM, I am using FD package in R and the code asks for a community matrix, with measured plots as lines and species in columns; and an attribute matrix with species in lines and attributes in columns. The fact is that I have a matrix with measures taken in different environments repeatedly in time (2017, 2018) with species abundance in columns. I don´t have individual values by area or year.

|  | spp_1 | spp_2 | spp_3 | spp_4 | spp_5 | spp_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5S17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3S17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1S17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| 2S17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5C18 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5V18 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5S18 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5E18 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2C18 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 95 |

**Question 1**: Can I use this as the community matrix to calculate CWM?

My functional trait matrix is as below:

|  | K | H1 | Lo | S1 | S2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spp_1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| spp_2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| spp_3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| spp_4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| spp_5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| spp_6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| spp_7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

**Question 2:** This is a functional groups matrix and the analysis mentions a functional traits matrix. The data that I have produces a diagonal 0/1 matrix with presence/ absent kind of data showing to which functional group the species belongs. Can I use this matrix to calculate CWM?

The code is running but I am not sure about the trustability of my results. Any comments or suggestions?